# Styling the Title Page in Article Class

Tags: article

I am writing a document in `article class`in `TeX`. I want the `title page` to look like the one [here](https://www.minneapolisfed.org/research/sr/sr328.pdf) , with all the content aligned to the left, a horizontal line starting just after the word ABSTRACT and another horizontal line underneath the abstract. I initially played with `hline` and `hlinefill` but it threw up errors when I used them either inside or outside `abstract` environment. What I have now produces the standard `title page`. How can I produce a `title page` like the one above? Here's the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Something Goes Here}
\author{Dr X\\ University of Dr X}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\hlinefill

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \maketitle.  You could just format the page as a page.  It helps to look at the code in article.cls (base folder).

Comment: I see. But I have always been using `\maketitle` and want to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

Tis is easy with the `abstract` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[style]{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstitlestyle}[1]{\raggedright\MakeUppercase#1\enspace\hrulefill\smallskip}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absparindent}{0pt}
\title{Something Goes Here}
\author{Dr Nutty\\ University of Nonsense}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\noindent\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I can now write the abstract the way I wanted. I still though could not figure out a way to left align the author name, affiliation and date. I played with `flushleft` and `\raggedright` but it didn't do anything. Any chance you know how to do it?

Comment: I managed to align to the left the article title and author name. Thank you to everybody who contributed their time. I have one more question -- how can I put the date at the top above the article title, as in the paper I mentioned in my question?